# How to respond some form parameters after processing request from HttpListenerContext in .net (C# )

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I am working with an Httplistenr which request I am processing via HttpListenerContext.

Previously I was just sending an `Ok` http response with out any content, now I need to respond with a couple of parameters like `Field1 = A, Field2 = B`.

I have set the `response.ContentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I don't know how to add the response values to the response.

My current method is

```
  private void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
  {        
        if (context.Request.Headers != null && context.Request.Headers.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append($"Request Headers {Environment.NewLine}");
            ..
        }             

        if (context.Request.InputStream != null)
        {
            using (var body = context.Request.InputStream)
            {
                var encoding = context.Request.ContentEncoding;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding))
                {
                    var conentRecieved  = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    ..,
                }
            }
        }

        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";             
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.StatusDescription = "OK";
        response.ContentLength64 = 0;
        response.OutputStream.Close();
        response.Close();            
}
```

I know how to send json type or simple text by setting respective content type and setting the content

Comment: Servers typically never form encoding or url encoding.  Instead use JSON.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i am not implementing my own standard here. There is a third  party api which call my callback wich is running in background windows service. in that callback after processing i have to respond as per required data. with this two fields. they are basically sending a get request on our callback with some possible data in header as well.

Comment: I am just asking how to add paramters

Comment: The answer to the other question explains that clearly.  That’s why this question is a dupe.

Comment: I am using HttpListener which is running under a background service, please refer me any lines there where some content has been set in httplistener response ? This is a pure C# object usage question while that question is bascially for which cotent type to use . i am forced to respond in formdata/formurlencoded paramters by third party

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send a string in the response body with HttpListener you either encode the string to a `byte[]` and use `response.OutputStream.Write()` and a `content-length` header.  Or just write start writing to it with a `System.IO.StreamWriter` and it will internally either use buffering and a `content-length` header, or use chunked transfer coding.

eg:

```
var response = context.Response;
response.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
var responseString = "MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo";
var responseBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
response.ContentLength64 = responseBody.Length;
response.OutputStream.Write(responseBody, 0, responseBody.Length);
response.Close();
```